# With Bazels `http_archive` - is there a way to add already existing files to the extracted sources?

Tags: bazel, patch, bazel-rules

With Bazel I'm building an external library using `http_archive` together with
some patches which bring additional features:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
    http_archive(
        name="some-lib",
        build_file="@my-project//some-lib:BUILD.some-lib",
        url="https://example/download/some-lib.tar.gz",
        sha256="8d9405baf113a9f25e4fb961d56f9f231da02e3ada0f41dbb0fa4654534f717b",
        patches=[
            "//some-lib/patches:01-add-additional-features.dif",
        ],
        patch_args=["-p1"],
        patch_tool="patch",
    )
```

The file structure looks like this:

```
some-lib
├── BUILD
├── BUILD.some-lib
├── include/additional_features.h
├── some-lib.bzl
└── patches
    ├── 01-add-additional-features.dif
    └── BUILD
```

This basically works but I still struggle with adding `include/additional_features.h`
into the extracted source folder.

I first tried to just list the file in the `filegroup` I use to later run
`configure_make` like this:

```
filegroup(
    name="all_srcs",
    srcs=glob(["**"]) + ["@my-project//some-lib:include/additional_features.h"],
)
```

then I'm getting

```
no such target '//some-lib:includes/additional_features.h': target 'includes/additional_features.h' not declared in package 'some-lib'; however, a source file of this name exists.
```

My next idea was to use the tools `http_archive` provides to make the file part of the source folder.
While you can use `patches` to modify the extracted folder you'd need a dedicated
`dif` file just to create the extra header file, which then you would have to
create in advance (i.E. create a Bazel rule) and declare it a dependency etc..
which I'd like to avoid to keep things simple.

There is also `patch_cmds` which next to `patches` can be used to modify the
extracted source folder by running arbitrary bash commands so I tried something like this:

```
    patch_cmds=[
        "cp @my-project//some-lib:include/additional_features.h include/",
    ],
```

but this does not work for me, I'm getting

```
Error in fail: Error applying patch command cp @my-project//some-lib:include/additional_features.h include/:
cp: cannot stat '@my-project//some-lib:include/additional_features.h': No such file or directory
```

So it looks like the syntax for specifying a path like I do with `build_file` does
not work with `patch_cmds` or that file can't be accessed at that specific stage.

Does one of the approaches I tried actual work and I just didn't use the right
syntax?

What's the Bazel-way to add (a bunch of) readily available files (i.e. in the same
repository as the Bazel-rules I provide) to a `http_archive` based source directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message already suggests to use `exports_files`.

Try putting

```
exports_files(
    ["include/additional_features.h"],
    visibility=["//visibility:public"],
)
```

in `some-lib/BUILD`, so that Bazel will let you reference source files from the `//some-lib` package in the external repository (and elsewhere).

You might then have to reference it in your rule to be able to use it. E.g. a `configure_make` could look like this:

```
configure_make(
    name="my_library",
    lib_source=":all_srcs",
    build_data=["@some-project//some-lib:include/additional_features.h"],
    copts=[
        "-I$EXT_BUILD_ROOT/include",
    ],

    ...

)
```

Comment: yes it does, and with `exports_files` you can allow a file to be part of your input files, but can you place it somewhere specific? The only way I managed `additional_features.h` to be inside the `includes/` directory was to create a patch file and apply it with `http_archive.patches`

Comment: i.e. to avoid the `patch` approach, I'd need a way within `filegroup` to map it's contents to another path, or any other way to make `additional_features.h` be added to the registered header files.

Comment: you could add the other directory to the compiler search path with `-I`, too